# How to link from a page to another in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I know that in HTML, if we have a button we want to link it to another page we use the tags below:       `<a href="#"> button </a>`

However I tried this for grail it did not work, it is taking me to a blank page:

in views/admin/admin.gsp I have a button that I am trying to link to 
   views/admin/gm.gsp

```
<li><a href="Users\mzein\file_down\grails-app\views\admin\gm.gsp">GM</a></li>
```

I also tried the `<g:link>` tag:

```
<g:link resource="gm">
```

but it did not work and took me to error no path page. What is the problem am I specifying the wrong path ? or is that not how it works in grails ?

I know how to use controllers but is that the only to go from one page to another ?

I would like to use URL mapping for such a task

```
    class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{

        }
        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "/views/admin/gm"(resources:'gm')
    }
}

<g:link resource="gm">GM</g:link>
```

Comment: I failed to understand what your problem is... `I also tried the <g:link> tag but it did not work.` how you tried it and how exactly it didn't work?

Comment: `href="Users\mzein\file_down\grails-app\views\admin\gm.gsp"`? seriously? You need to read how the MVC works in grails.

Comment: I tend to agree with @codehx. You should really read on how to use `<g:link>` https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html. and the whole grails documentation as well

Comment: I do not want to use controllers @injecteer, please check the edit I would like to use URL mapping.

Comment: are you using it as a rest service ? Example Usage for a RESTful Resource: static mappings = {
    "/books"(resources: 'book')
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `createLink` tag with `uri` attribute like:

`<li><a href="${createLink(uri:'/somepath/gm.gsp')}">GM</a></li>`

**Edit:**
ok then you need to do the request mapping in `UrlMappings.groovy` file like

```
"/foo/bar"(view: "path/test")
```

and make a corresponding request via `g:link` as

`<g:link controller="foo" action="bar" name="someName">GM</g:link>` 
and **path** is the path of directory in views folder in which **test.gsp** is present.

Comment: I would like to use URL mapping please check the edit

Answer (score 1):

The way you need to hit a resource is

```
/appName/controller/action
```

and

```
/appName/controller/action?params for GET request
```

You can alternatively use

```
<g:link controller="controller" action="action"></g:link>
```

or alternatively

```
<a href="${createLink(controller: 'controller', action: 'action')}">link</a>
```